# What if I want to post an answer to a question which I feel is not there in SE?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently I have been searching for an answer not only in SO but in the whole universe. And GOD seems to play with me by not providing me the answer :).

As I have searched everywhere it seems I am close to that and I plan to share this with other users in SO, so that others can get advantage of that.

So should I create a post for that or what should I do?

Comment: It really depends on what kind of question it is. But kudos for asking beforehand!

Comment: If you have a programming problem that you believe others will have, that you can clearly describe and you have a solution to - then by all means ask and answer the question yourself.

Comment: Definitely it is a programming problem related to apache derby and netbeans for which I found a lot of posts here but not a single one served my purpose. Even though I tried all of them. My bad luck that all these raised hell to my programming scenario. So, I decided to do such a thing. Hope it will help..

Comment: I would like to **humbly request** the **user** who has **downvoted** my question to please explain if I have done any wrong by asking this type of a question. Please tell me the correct way of asking such a question.

Comment: If you decide to post the question before you finish solving it, be sure to include what you've already tried. No sense in other people trying or suggesting something you already know won't work. (It will also show research effort.)

Comment: @BSMP .Thanks!!!. I was afraid of posting such a question as it already has some accepted answers and good comments. Will it be ok to post a question like you have said and refer to the questions which did not solve my problem?

Answer (score 3):

If it's an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question not yet asked, go ahead and ask it.
If you can, you are also ecouraged to self-answer.

We cannot say anything more about it, as you forgot to mention any specifics.

Comment: Yes, i will definitely do that. The question I was searching was about apache derby embedded database and netbeans. It gave me one hell of a bad experience. So I decided to solve it by hook or by crook and post it here.. :)